# How to replace griddata content when another control's (e.g. combobox) selection is changed?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

This is probably not that difficult but as a wpf/mvvm beginner I'm still struggling with some basics.

I have a combobox (acts like a filter) and a griddata in a view.  I use MMVM and databinding.  On startup griddata is populated and the combobox's selection is set - that works fine.  I'd like to replace the content of the griddata when the selection in the combobox changes.  The combobox selected value is bound to a property in my viewmodel so I know when it changes and I can easily replace the content of the collection (which is IList) bound to the griddata.  However I do not know how to force the griddata to 'refresh' itself in the view using mvvm bindings.

I was considering using ObservableCollection<> but from what I've read it looks like replacing the content is not that simple either.  I do not really need the view to know when a single item in the collection changes - I will always replace the whole content of the list.

I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in you `ViewModel` and call it when the `List` changes.

Example:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<MyObject> _myList;

    public List<MyObject> MyList
    {
        get { return _myList; }
        set { _myList = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Now when you replace `MyList` e.g. `MyList = newlist` it will tell the UI to update whatever is bound to `MyList`